# Minimum size of JFace application window

Tags: java, swt, jface

I am at the beginning with GUI programming in JFace/SWT. Before I worked with an normal SWT window (http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wb.ercp.doc.user%2Fhtml%2Fwizards%2FeRCP%2Fapplication_window.html) and today I've tried the JFace Application Window for the first time.

Now I want to set a minimum size of this window.. In SWT it worked with

```
shell.setMinimumSize(100,100)
```

but in my the org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow there is no such method..

I've tried

```
this.createShell().setMinimumSize(100, 100);
```

(my implementation "public class MainView extends ApplicationWindow {")

but it doesn't work.

```
this.getShell()
```

returns null.

By the way, I searched for a good documentation about JFace in gernal, for now especially for the Application Window. But I couldn't find anything really good and extensive.

The documentation in SWT, especially JFace is very dispairing.. Too bad, because there are nice features in it.

What are your experiences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override the `configureShell` method and set the minimum size there:

```
@Override
protected void configureShell(Shell newShell)
{
  super.configureShell(newShell);

  newShell.setMinimumSize(100, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the documentation of the *createShell* method, it creates a new shell. You need to use existing/created shell of your window.

You can get it from the parent composite of your application. Please see the *createContents* method in the following snippet:

```
package helloproject;

import org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;

public class HelloWorld extends ApplicationWindow {

    public HelloWorld() {
        super(null);
    }

    /**
     * Runs the application
     */
    public void run() {
        setBlockOnOpen(true);
        open();
        Display.getCurrent().dispose();
    }

    protected Control createContents(Composite parent) {
        // Create a Hello, World label
        Label label = new Label(parent, SWT.CENTER);
        label.setText("Hello, World");

        // Set the minimum size
        parent.getShell().setMinimumSize(200, 200);

        return label;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HelloWorld().run();
    }
}
```